# ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs not found when using StructureMap

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, runtime-error, structuremap

I get the following error when debugging (F5) my code in Visual Studio (2017):

> ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs not found

Reading the detail, it seems to be looking for a file on my computer in the following place:

> 'c:\Home\Chris\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs'

I don't have a directory *'c:\Home\Chris...'* and I have no idea why it would be looking there.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

(Answering own question)

I spent days looking for an answer.

I noticed that I started getting the issue after I had installed StructureMap. I managed to solve it with the help of this [explanation.](http://biasecurities.com/2012/06/configuring-mvc-4-with-structuremap/)

In short, I had to install **CommonServiceLocator v2.0.1.** using NuGet. Once I did that I then had to update this file:

*StructureMapDependencyScope.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http.Dependencies;
//using Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation 
using StructureMap;
using CommonServiceLocator;                  

namespace UI.DependencyResolution
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The structure map dependency scope.
    /// </summary>
    public class StructureMapDependencyScope : ServiceLocatorImplBase, IDependencyScope
    {
```

I added a reference to `CommonServiceLocator` and removed the reference to `Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation`.

This removed the hard dependency on `c:\Home\Chris...`.

Hope that helps others.

Comment: Kudos to you Alex.  I spent hours working on this until I finally did the right google search.  I already had CommonServiceLocator in the project.  I just had to remove the old using and add the new one to CommonServiceLocator.  THANK YOU.